# question about overriding initialize method

Tags: ruby

I encountered a strange question about override initialize message of BigDecimal.

```
class Test1 < String
  def initialize(a, b)
    puts a
    puts b
  end
end

require 'bigdecimal'
class Test2 < BigDecimal
  def initialize(a, b)
    puts a
    puts b
  end
end

>> Test1.new('a', 'b')
a
b
>> Test2.new('a', 'b')
TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Fixnum)
    from (irb):17:in `new'
    from (irb):17
```

Why I can override the initialize message of String, but not of BigDecimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into sources of Ruby classes, you'll see that the `String` class defines method `String#initialize`, which is called after `String#new` (inherited from `Object`) for allocating a new instance. You don't call `String#initialize` (or `#super`) in your new instance so you got `""` when you inspect the newly created object.

`BigDecimal` defines method `Bigdecimal#new`, which allocates its own object. Object creation consists of two parts - allocating space for new object and initializing it. You only defined initializing new object, so you stay with default allocating space for object. If you want to override it, you should define `#new` in your new class and call `BigDecimal`'s `#new` with proper arguments.

Hope that clarifies a little what happen in your example.

Comment: I want to enlighten this a bit more. Since ruby does not allow overloading, it will only allow one `initialize' method. The last defined method will be the only valid one. Also it will only allow one `new' method. Normally the new method (defined on Object) calls the initialize method, but as mentioned here: the BigDecimal `new' is different :) So you need to redefine the `self.new' although that is not the preferred way. Remember to call 'super' with the correct parameters, or you won't have a BigDecimal.

Normally you would not have to define new,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BigDecimal implements the new class method and if you override that in your test2 class then you can write your Test2 initialize method in any way you want, for e.g.

```
class Test2 < BigDecimal
  def self.new(a)
    puts a
  end

  def initialize(a)
    puts a
  end
end

Test2.new("a")
```

The class method new is the object constructor which sets up the object state and allocates memory once the object is initialized by using the initialize method.

But generally we don't implement the new method as it is the default constructor method provided by ruby although it can be overridden by redefining it in your class if there is a strong reason for doing that and that is what BigDecimal has done.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some type checking occurring in `BigDecimal.new()`, which is getting upset before your overridden `initialize` is reached. See point 19 in [this list](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_summary5.html)

It's not often an issue (I remembered something but still had to look it up) but there's a `new` class method that, if I recall correctly, actually creates the object and then calls `initialize`.

Overriding `new` on the class, thus:

```
class Test2 < BigDecimal
  def Test2.new(a, b)
    puts a
    puts b
  end
end

Test2.new('42', 'banana')
```

gives the hoped-for answer.